# Leibniz series Loop not converging

Tags: java, loops

So I decided to tryout the Leibniz series (PI ESTIMATOR)

```
PI/4 = 1/3 - 1/5 + 1/7 - 1/9 + 1/11 etc...
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PIEstimator{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of Iterations:");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        double sum = 0;
        
        //START OF Leibniz series
        for (int i=1; i < n; i++) {
            double calculations = Math.pow(-1,i + 1) / (2 * i + 1);
            sum = sum += calculations;
            System.out.println(sum + 3);
       }
    }
}
```

And here is my output if `n = 12`

```
3.3333333333333335
3.1333333333333333
3.276190476190476
3.165079365079365
3.255988455988456
3.179065379065379
3.2457320457320455
3.186908516320281
3.2395400952676496
3.1919210476486017
3.235399308518167
```

#### My Question:

Why is the output not converging to 3.14159265.......?

Is my math incorrect?

Than you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
for (int i=1; i < n; i++) {
    double calculations = Math.pow(-1,i + 1) / (2 * (i-1) + 1);
    sum += calculations;
}
System.out.println(4*sum);
```

- First, the first denominator must be 1 so `2*(i-1) + 1 = 0 + 1  = 1.`
- Second, remember that the series computes `pi/4` so you need to mutiply by `4`.

Here is a suggestion.  Instead of doing the Math.pow overhead, just use a ternery operator (`?:`)to see if `i` is even or odd and change the sign accordingly.

```
  double calculations = ((i % 2) == 0 ? -1. : 1.) / (2.*(i-1)+1);
```

Comment: It seems your code runs well but it goes into the 2.6666 range; I want it to be always in a 3. range Nevertheless, your answer is very clean!

Comment: The first iteration is always going to be 2.6666.  That is the nature of the algorithm.  I moved the final answer outside the loop so you don't get all the iterations.  But my algorithm is correct.  I also explained what you were doing incorrectly.

Comment: That cleared things up for me, thanks, I will accept your answer since it does 100% answer my question!

Comment: Upvoting this question would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I accidentally unaccepted your answer, now it is reaccepted

Answer (score 1):

This works fine(I tested it):

```
for (int i=1; i < n; i++) {
    double calculations = Math.pow(-1,i) / (2 * i + 1);
    sum += calculations;
    System.out.println((sum + 1) * 4);
}
```

Comment: @Jackov Kusic After many runs I have figured out that it does indeed work fine, I just limited the number of loops!

Comment: But your answer only tells me that it works, but if you look at @WJS answer it shows me another way the algorithm could work!